# How to escape quotes in shell within both usage of ssh and sudo?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sed, quoting

**In one word:**

question and example could test locally:

```
sh -c "echo 'how to print single quote here'"
```

**details:**

I have a config like this:

```
upload_server = ('192.168.1.1', 10051)
```

now I need a shell script to replace server config.
Locally I can do it with sed:

```
sed -E 's/(    upload_server = ).*/\\1('\"'$a'\"', 10051)/g' config.py
```

but there's huge amount of machines have to change the config.

a proper plan is to use `ssh` with for..in:

```
for i in `cat hosts`; do ssh $i "cmd"; done
```

but to change config also need a `sudo`, it looks like this:

```
for i in `cat hosts`; do ssh $i "sudo -c \"cmd\""; done
```

and now within sed:

```
upload_server=123.123.123.123
upload_server_port=1000
cmd="sed -E 's/(    upload_server = ).*/\\1('\"\"'\"'${upload_server}'\"'\"\"', ${upload_server_port})/g' config.py"
ssh $i "sudo -c \"${cmd}\""
```

the result of config:

```
upload_server = (123.123.123.123, 1000)
```

which should be like this:

```
upload_server = ('123.123.123.123', 1000)
```

Now I'm confused a lot in quotes usage. :(

Comment: `sudo -c`? Why not just `sudo cmd`?

Comment: this can help do a reduction of quotes, but there is still problem...

Comment: Even someone who would feel comfortable in escaping them properly would chose not to do it that way because it is too confusing for nothing.  Why don't you write a nice little script and `scp` it to the target before running it?  That is much simpler, clearer, and adaptable.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Yes, this is a simplest way. But a one-line-script looks the same as hold a candle to the sun.

Comment: What's about if you write your upload_server without quotes? `upload_server = (192.168.1.1, 10051)`. Anyway, for your purpose, I think that it will be easier for you to use some automation tool like ansible (https://github.com/ansible/ansible)

Comment: `'s/(    upload_server = ).*/\\1('\"'$a'\"', 10051)/g'` = `s/(    upload_server = ).*/\1("$a", 10051)/g`

Comment: I use python file for config, so must be interpreted by python. quotes(double-quote or single-quote) must be there. @ZumodeVidrio looks like a heavy tool, but maybe a good idea, will try in future, thanks.

Comment: @richard this code works awesome too. thanks!

Comment: For anyone finding this (7 years later) I tried for more than a day with this approach and variants and I never could get the script with `sed` commands to not throw errors at the remote.  Even using `sed` to escape the single quotes!  Who knows what other commands will have the same issue.  So really just go with what @JuliePelletier says as this is "a big waste of time".  I wrote a script that copies the local script with scp to a temp file then runs that script (via ssh) and then deletes the temp script with ssh.  Ok it's 3 commands but it's in a script so it operates like one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can bypass the quoting issue entirely by passing the sed script on standard input. SSH routes the local standard input to the remote process, sudo just leaves it open, and sed can read its script on stdin. You can pass content for stdin with a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

```
for i in `cat hosts`; do
  ssh "$i" 'sudo sed -f - …' <<'EOF'
s/(    upload_server = ).*/\1("$a", 10051)/g
EOF
done
```

More generally, you can pass a shell snippet on stdin through SSH without worrying about quoting, as long as you don't need to also pass data on stdin.

```
for i in `cat hosts`; do
  ssh "$i" sudo sh <<'EOF'
sed 's/(    upload_server = ).*/\1("$a", 10051)/g' …
EOF
done
```

It isn't clear from your question whether you intended to insert `"$a"` into the configuration file, or `"something"` where the value of the variable `a` in the local shell is `something`. If you want to refer to the local variable, then use a here document with interpolation, and protect `` $\` `` in the here document with backslashes. Note that due to the parsing by sed, and by the remote shell in the second snippet, the value of the variable must not contain any of the characters `\/'` or a newline.

```
  ssh "$i" sudo sh <<EOF
sed 's/(    upload_server = ).*/\\1("$a", 10051)/g' …
EOF
```

Comment: quotes works well, but $a cannot be interpreted...

Comment: @jixiang Did you mean `$a` to insert dollar-a in the configuration file, or to insert the content of the variable `a` defined in the shell on the local machine? This wasn't clear from your question. If you want to refer to the local variable (unlike the code snippet in your question), then you need to use a here document with interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ssh localhost sh -c \"echo \\\'how to print single quotes here\\\'\"
'how to print single quotes here'

$ ssh localhost echo \\\'how to print single quotes here\\\'
'how to print single quotes here'
```

To understand the rules, remember that one level of quoting is stripped by the local shell, then SSH invokes a remote shell which strips a second level of quoting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your answer maybe a misconception of my question. I mean inner the echo '', with an ' output. which echo is in "" . look my details for understand why I'm doing this.

Comment: @jixiang: `ssh localhost sh -c "\"echo \'how to print single quotes here\'\""`. You need doublequotes around `echo ...` because `sh -c` expects the command to be one single argument.

Comment: :) test pass on echo.... but on sed still not work.....very complicated....